# Подключение к БД firebird node js с использованием динамического пароля

Tags: javascript, node.js, циклы

Связка node js + electron с модулем node-firebird.
Необходимо создать подключение к БД. Из стандартного API node-firebird подключение происходит следующим образом

```
options.host = 'host';
options.port = port;
options.database = 'path';
options.user = 'SYSDBA';
options.password = pass;

Firebird.attach(options, function (err, db) { .. }
```

Пароль к БД создаётся динамически с использованием функций генератора

```
GetDinamicPass(число)
```

Число может быть от 1 до 999.

Подскажите, каким циклом организовать автоматический подбор пароля? При отсутствии подключения пробовать следующий: `GetDinamicPassByCode(число+1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось реализовать через итерацию

```
for (i = 0; i < кол-во возможных комбинаций; i++)
```

Далее в теле цикла пробуем подключение к БД
Задаём пароль для подключения:

```
opt.password: GetDinamicPass(начальное значение + i)
```

Реализуем само подключение

```
Firebird.attach(opt, function (err, svc) {
            if (err)
                return;
            if (svc) {
                alert("Найдено!");
}
```